# What is the Google Closure Compiler REST API request limit?

Tags: minify, google-closure-compiler

Performing too many requests from the Closure Compiler API you get this error:

```
Error(22): Too many compiles performed recently.  Try again later.
```

What is the actual/current limit? Is it an hourly limit? A rolling window?

Any documentation on how this is calculated? The only information about this I could find is on this page (search for "abuse"): https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_ui?hl=en

Comment: Google nowhere mentions the limit, although the limit is *probably* a number of requests made in the last hour ("You have submitted too many compiles from your machine. After an hour, you should be able to perform compiles again.") --- Out of curiosity, how many requests did you do? Also, can't you switch to the offline Java compiler?

Comment: I made probably between 10 and 30 in a row. But it is just an estimate. Also, define "last hour"? I also don't want to install java in the server because I want to avoid updates of both java and the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are per minute/per hour/per day caps.  This is not currently documented, but I believe it the caps allow a sustained rate of ~1 per minute.  In my experience when people run into this problem, they would would be either happier with the command-line tool, or a local compilation server like Plovr or are hitting it by accident (i.e. they don't realize that they are continuously hitting the web service).